# How to compare two CSV files using pySpark and validating exist or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, csv, pyspark

So, I have a input.csv something like this:

```
First_Name  Last_Name   Birthdate   Gender  Email_ID        Mobile
Smit        Will        21-04-1974  M       da1@gmail.com   5224521452
Bob         Builder     14-03-1992  M       ad4@gmail.com   2452586253
```

And Database.csv with few more records to it:

```
First_Name  Last_Name   Birthdate   Gender  Email_ID        Mobile
Bob         Micheles    10-04-1982  M       ya4@gmail.com   7845214525
Will        Smith       21-04-1974  M       da1@gmail.com   9874521452
Emma        Watson      21-08-1989  F       emma@gmail.com  5748214563
Emma        Smit        21-08-1999  F       da1@gmail.com   9874521452
bob         robison     14-03-1992  M       za@gmail.com    2452586253
```

`df_DataBase = spark.read.csv("DataBase.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)`
My expected out is:

1. Bob Builder is the same as that of Bob robison as only his *Last_Name* and *Email_ID* are different
2. Smit Will and Will Smith are the same as only the *Names* and the *mobile number* is different.
   and finally print the if they exist or not in the existing input file like this:

[image: Expected Output]

NOTE: The person is not same when email, phone and birthdate don't match.

Thus using pyspark if we can achieve this I would be great.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. If I understand correct, the person is not same when email, phone and birthdate don't match?

Comment: Yes you have understood it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below:

```
ip = spark.read.csv("input.csv")
db = spark.read.csv("database.csv")
#condition if person is same
person_exists = [((col('a.Email_id') == col('b.Email_id')) | (col('a.Mobile') == col('b.Mobile')) | (col('a.Birthdate') == col('b.Birthdate'))) ]

#people existing in db
existing_persons = 
ip.alias('a').join(db.alias('b'),person_exists,"inner").select([col('a.'+x) for x in a.columns])

#people not existing in db
non_existing = ip.subtract(existing_persons)

#add a column to indicate if same person or not
existing_persons = existing_persons.withColumn('Same_Person',lit('Yes'))
non_existing = non_existing.withColumn('Same_Person',lit('No'))
```

Comment: Thank You Swetha, I truly appreciate your time.

Swetha a quick understanding, is it possible to compare within the same file, if I have the same email_id, birthdate, and mobile number repeated for a person with different first name and last name can I find out that? @SwethaShanmugam